# NetBeans JRE glitch?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm hoping the combined minds of stackoverflowers can outwit the NetBeans forum!

I seem to have a problem when testing my applications through the NetBeans "run project".  The first frame appears normally, but subsequent dialogs I have created turn black either immediately or after mousing over a component (the window decoration appears as normal though).  Resizing the dialog seems to repair things or mousing over individual interactive components seems to repaint them.  If I build the project and run from outside NetBeans, it behaves normally.  I'm pretty sure it's not my projects' code as I have tried my projects on my laptop and all behaves normally.  I've also imported the example anagram game into NetBeans on my PC, and the about dialog turns black via "run project" too.  I've tried different versions of NetBeans (7.3.1 and 7.4RC) but the same happens in both.  I believe that both my PC and laptop are up to date with the version of Java.  The main thing that's different between my two machines is that one is Windows 7 64 bit (PC) and the laptop is the 32 bit version - could it be something to do with this?

Anyone know what might be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Problems with Swing applications are often caused by faulty/old video drivers. Try turning off direct draw using the JVM property: `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response.  Tried using the switch both in the config file and from the commands line - no change :o(  Just out of curiosity, I tried the opengl switch too.  It reduced the frequency in which the frames went black, but it also made netbeans very unresponsive...

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "config file". You should apply that setting for the JVM running *your* program, not NetBeans. Inside  NetBeans you need to add that to the "Run" configuration of your *project*.

Comment: Woops!  Added the switch to my project (rather than to netbeans itself in the netbeans.conf file) and no more black frames!  Thank you very much - Problem resolved!